# sql server how to retrieve only rows that have been changed in xmldocument

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am using a sql query with a sqldatareader to create an my xmlfile with data from a sqltable. This query basically retrieves the full content of a table. I am trying to find a way to just query the updated rows with my query the next time I construct the xmlfile for a performance benefit? Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to mark updated rows on database level. An additional column will be necessary, like last_updated (datetime). So you can execute the query any time by passing the date/time your application executed the last time.

The new last_updated column can be automatically set with a trigger.

I hope this helps.

Comment: On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog.